# Intuition on $L$ in Euler's error

Tags: numerical-methods

An upper bound for the  global error in Euler's method to solve a first order ODE numerically is given by the equation
\begin{equation}
  \frac{Mh}{2L} ( e^{L(t_{i+1}-a)} - 1),
\end{equation}
where $t_{i+1}$ is the $i+1$ cell in the abcsisa and $a$ is the 
first abcisa. M is a bound for the second derivative of the ODE unknown
$y$ and $L$ is the Lipschitz continuity property bound.
This is derived in most of numerical analysis books.

My question is the following: Having $L$ small is good  for convergence and stability (right?) in
the sense that $L$ small implies little change. If $L=0$ then
the function $f(t,y)$ (on the right hand side of the ODE) is constant on $y$.  If $L <1$ the function is contracting.  So why is $L$ in the denominator
of the bound? My intuition (which is not working good) says that the error bound should diminish as $L$ diminshes.

What is wrong with  my intuition here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First this bound is not a good estimation. It is useful to say the error is bounded, but in practice it is completely inaccurate.
Then the error does not explode when $L\rightarrow 0$. You can develop $\frac{1}{L}(e^{L(t_{i+1}−a)}−1)=\frac{1}{L}(1+L(t_{i+1}−a)+O(L^2)−1)=t_{i+1}−a+O(L)$. So you see that the error diminishes as $L$ tends to $0$, which is logical.